# Is it necessary to compute modulo 1,000,000,007 (10^9+7) in python3?

Tags: python-3.6, modulo

While solving competitive programming questions, sometimes it is asked to compute the final answer as 
" Since this number may be large, compute it modulo 1,000,000,007 (10^9+7) ".
Also, it is the fact that in python3 plain int type is unbounded.
So, it is necessary to compute modulo 10^9+7 if I am solving my programming question in python 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what anyone here believes is fair or warranted. What matters is what the automated system or human in charge expects as an answer.

Of course, since doing modular operations can slow down a possible solution within a given time frame, it would be best to find an optimum alternative, if permitted.